# Reading joblib file from Azure Blob in python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, joblib

I am trying to read a `joblib` file from Azure blob (see code below). However, I get the following error:

> ```
> with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2: invalid start byte
> ```

Code:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient
import sklearn.externals
import joblib

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string('connection_string', 'myContainer', 'myBlob.joblib')
downloaded_blob = blob_client.download_blob()
model = joblib.load(downloaded_blob.readall())
```

`pickle` has `loads()` which works fine. How can I achieve the same with joblib?

Answer (score 1):

I used readinto instead of readall (to get a stream and avoid encoding problems) and then used a temporary file to read the path into

```
def read_blob_model(azure_storage_connectionstring, container_name, path):
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(azure_storage_connectionstring, container_name, path)
    downloaded_blob = blob_client.download_blob()
    temp_file = tempfile.mkstemp()
    with open(temp_file[1], 'wb') as f:
        downloaded_blob.readinto(f)
        return temp_file[1]

temp_file = read_blob_model(azure_storage_connectionstring, container_name, roomtype_model)
model = joblib.load(temp_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Joblib can also read from `BytesIO` instead of a file:

```
import BytesIO
import joblib

model_binary = BytesIO()
blob_client.download_blob().readinto(model_binary)
model = joblib.load(model_binary)
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue due to reading file  that contains  the special characters

Python tries to convert a byte-array (a bytes which it assumes to be a utf-8-encoded string) to a unicode string (str). This process of course is a decoding according to utf-8 rules. When it tries this, it encounters a byte sequence which is not allowed in utf-8-encoded strings (namely this 0xff at position 0).

Use this solution it will strip out (ignore) the characters and return the string without them. Only use this if your need is to strip them not convert them

```
with open(path, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as value:
```

Using `errors='ignore'` You'll just lose some characters. but if your don't care about them as they seem to be extra characters originating from a the bad formatting and programming of the clients connecting to my socket server. Then its a easy direct solution .

Reference:https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type

Another way to fix problem

change the encoding method. Also, you can find other encoding method here [standard-encodings](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)

Comment: My problem is that 'downloaded_blob.readall()' is not a path. If I found the azure path (including authentication) to my blob, then your solution would definitely help.